My Flask application only loads the urls when running on http, but not on https
I am trying to run a flask application on an Ec2 ubuntu, instance, I am using nginx and gunicorn for the same. The problem that I am facing is that on http I can access my urls but on https only the default i.e "/" is working
Example : http://nearhire.app/get_skillsets - returns the proper values but https://nearhire.app/get_skillsets returns a 404 error
The same urls when ran on port 5000 works perfectly.
So http://nearhire.app:5000/get_skillsets works
My gunicorn set is :
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance for Job Application
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/JobProject
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers=4 --timeout=60 main:app
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and my nginx structure (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default) is :
upstream jobapplication {
server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                proxy_pass http://jobapplication;

        }
    }
server {

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.nearhire.app nearhire.app; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://jobapplication;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            include proxy_params;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nearhire.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nearhire.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

    server {
        if ($host = www.nearhire.app) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
        if ($host = nearhire.app) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
    
            listen 80 ;
            listen [::]:80 ;
        server_name nearhire.app;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    }

PS : all the apis (Except the default one '/') return jsonified values, they do not load any page whatsoever (The reason I am using nginx is for letenscrypt ssl)
Do let me know if any additional information is required

Okay so it turns out all that was required was for me to remove the try_files $uri $uri/ =404; , from the location/ block
This is because the try_files $uri $uri/ =404, tries to serve the file with the urlname, else will search for a directory if no file is found. In my case, I didnt require this functionality, as my apis were only returning jsonified values.
